# Trouble Creating a Simple Automated Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I have created a simple automated email and in the configure area it's asking for a subscriber Date Attribute, but in the drop down menu it says, "No attributes defined". How do I go about defining attributes and where do I go in Marketing cloud to do so?

Comment: Please update your question with the steps you've taken to create your email.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/create_an_email/simple_automated_emails/

Please go through the documentation and create the custom attribute.

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/profile_and_preference_attributes/

Create the relevant subscriber attribute :

- Click Subscribers.
- Click Profile Management or Preference Management.
- Click Create.
- Define the properties for this attribute.

  - A Custom date attribute can be created accordingly
- Click OK in the Attribute Properties dialog box when done.
- Update the subscribers value for this newly created Attribute if needed.

Comment: Please quote some relevant information from the links as link only answers are too prone to getting made irrelevant if the links break.  See [answer]

Comment: @DaveHumm , Thanks for the suggestion. Hope that clears the steps towards resolution.